# Send parameters from child to parent navigator React native

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, stack-navigator, tabnavigator

I am using React native and redux. One of my actions in redux needs to update the badge count on one of my bottom tab navigator tab. SetParams doesn't work anywhere outside the screen so how can I set parameters for the bottom tab navigator from one of the screens under it so that it receives those props?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are using redux why not save the counter in the state and just take the data from store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are using Redux I would just recommend storing the badge count in your store and pass it in that way.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am using now and it kind of solved the problem of accessing the variable. But each refresh looks very funny with the badge count updating. Thanks for the help!